# Поиск в БД текстовых значений

Tags: mysql, datagrip

столкнулся с проблемой, есть список эл.почт, по ним нужно сделать поиск в БД(номер заказа, стоимость И так далее), столкнулся с проблемой что каждую новую эл почту нужно вручную заключать в апостроф, возможно есть проще метод, например выделить весь список эл.почт и нажать сочетание клавиш? Работаю в Data Grip, таких горячих клавиш увы не нашел. Работающий запрос:

```
select 
orders.order_number,
       orders.created_at,
       total_price,
       os.title,
       email,
       pt.name,
       dt.name
from orders
join payment_types pt on orders.payment_type_id = pt.id
join delivery_types dt on orders.delivery_type_id = dt.id
join order_statuses os on orders.status_id = os.id
where email in ( 'bla@bla.bla',
                 'bla2@bla.bla'
...) and date(orders.created_at)>'2020-03-01'
order by date(orders.created_at);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Превратите список мыл в набор записей (`SELECT 'bla@bla.bla' AS email UNION SELECT 'bla2@bla.bla' UNION ...`) и JOIN его как ещё один источник данных. Альтернативный (но плохой по производительности) - объединить мылы в CSV и применить FIND_IN_SET()

Answer (score 0):

Да, вам нужен экстрактор One-Row. Выбериет его, затем в таблице выделите нужные  имеилы и нажмите Ctrl+C. Они скпируются в нужном вам виде, даже с запятыми.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если этот список у вас в CSV, откройте его и сделайте то же самое.

Comment: Если этот список у вас просто где-то лежит в текствоом формате, используйте мультикурсоры: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/guide/tips/multi-cursor/